# can c++filt be used to write the demangled name back in the .s file itself?

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-construction, g++, c++filt

I am just trying to learn c++filt, there are not enough example usage available in the web....

I am writing a main.cpp file and trying to read the machine code....

```
g++ -S main.cpp -> gives me main.s
```

if I need to find out an demangled value, I could use

```
g++ -S main.cpp | c++filt <demangled name>
```

eg)

```
g++ -S main.cpp | c++filt _Z3gooi
```

gives me value goo(int i)// which is the signature,

Is there a way, where you replace the current main.s file with demangled values, for example, the `_Z3gooi` will be demangled as goo(int i) in the file itself, instead of console.... ????

Comment: What is the pipe supposed to do?

Comment: pipe outputs the main.s....... so c++filt thats that as an input and finds the mangled name to the right and gives the demangled name.....

Comment: @howtechstuffworks But g++ doesn't write anything to stdout, so c++filt doesn't see anything.

Comment: I guess, c++filt directly takes an assembly file from the folder....

Comment: I just did c++filt file name.... it gave me the value... mystery though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done in

```
C++filt<main.s>temp.s
```

Answer (score 0):

No, because the demangled name will usually be invalid as a symbol name.